# how to filter Android StateFlow in Alphabetical order

Tags: android, kotlin, filter, kotlin-stateflow

how to filter Android  StateFlow  in Alphabetically  order

I have a StateFlow which gives the result based on names, I want to filter it to show the names Alphabetically how can we do this

```
var filterFlow = MutableStateFlow("")

 var filterValue: String
        get() = filterFlow.value
        set(value) {
            filterFlow.value = value
        }

val results: StateFlow<List<Persons>> =
        _query.asStateFlow()
            .combine(filterFlow) { list, filter ->
                list.filter { 
                    it.Name.contains(filter)
                }
            }
            .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, emptyList())
```

Comment: Doesn't `.sorted()` work?

Comment: I think you’re over-complicating your question by talking about flows. You just want to sort a list, right? I know that’s been answered here before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .map { ... } to transform each value or .transform { ... } to generalize filter and map operators:

```
private val _namesStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<List<String>>(emptyList())
val namesStateFlow = _namesStateFlow.asStateFlow()

namesStateFlow
    .map { list -> list.sortedBy { it } }
    .collect { sortedList -> /*to do something*/ }
```